# Android emulator doesn't boot

Tags: android, emulation

I have created an emulator many times, but everytime I launch one I get stuck onto the screen where a glossy `"Android"` text appears and nothing happens further. I have noticed in the logcat that it shows the message that the emulator is created, and even when I run apps from eclipse I can see in the console `"Installing application"`, sometimes it says `Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...` but nothing appears on the screen other than the Android text. For more info

My adt bundle: 22.6
Emulator api: google api 18 (as I need to test some playservice app)
snapshot enabled

But I am stuck here for months, in the meantime I used real device to test, but now I don't have any.
Any help?

Comment: Wait, waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaait. :'/

Comment: Last time I have waited almost 1.5 hours :(

Comment: Hey, you should try http://www.genymotion.com/ this is a independant Android emulator which boot in almost 5s. It's almost as easy as the default one to configure.

Comment: Will I be able to test playstore services like map, gcm on that?

Comment: I also recommend genymotion. You could try to disable snapshots and click on the emulator window in combination with changing focused window from time to time. In my case the emulator boots in ~15min roughly. (and maybe choose a different device to emulate)

Comment: I have installed genymotion and downloaded samsung galaxy s2 but it appears a white screen and nothing else